# Meaning of "and for the very complete enjoyment and very high sense of the distinction which her happy features announced."

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "His dancing proved to be just what she had believed it, extremely good; and Harriet would have seemed almost too lucky, **if it had not been for the cruel state of things before, and for the very complete enjoyment and very high sense of the distinction which her happy features announced**"

Context: the chapter 38 of Emma by Jane Austen opens with the characters arriving to the ball. At the last dance before dinner, Mr.Elton refused to dance with Harriet, when he is was asked by Mrs.Weston. His refusal with both his and his wife's conduct towards Harriet during the evening made her distressed. So Mr. Knightley decided to ask Harriet to a dance.

My question: in the bold part, I don't understand how "and for the very complete enjoyment and very high sense of the distinction which her happy
features announced." to be a reason for Harriet not to seem too lucky.

Comment: I agree. It doesn't make sense to me that "*complete enjoyment and ... her happy features*" would make her seem not as lucky. My take is that this is a literary analysis question rather than an English learning one.

Comment: "__Harriet would have seemed almost too lucky__" could mean people might have __deemed__ her too lucky, perhaps even have resented her luck. Then recalling her earlier plight, and seeing her utter enjoyment now and her evident awareness of the honour done her, perhaps people decided she **didn't** seem **too** lucky: they didn't resent her luck.